# BizTalk Imports only one row from CSV file

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

My BizTalk orchestration imports only 1 row.

I cannot figure out what is wrong, since there are no error messages or warnings.

I am using:

- WCF
- Orchestration
- Receive Pipeline
- Stored Procedure
- CSV Flat File

I think the issue is in the csv schema.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://ElecFFILEImport.FFILECSVSchema" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://ElecFFILEImport.FFILECSVSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
      <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" codepage="65001" default_pad_char=" " pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="speed" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="true" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" root_reference="FFILERoot" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="FFILERoot">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0xD 0xA" child_order="postfix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element name="Header">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0xD 0xA" child_order="infix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="Header_Row" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Detail">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter="," child_order="infix" sequence_number="2" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="FFILECompany" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="AccountName" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="HomeAddress" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="AccountNumber" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="4" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="ServiceNumber" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="5" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="BNumber" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="6" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="DS" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="7" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="LPC" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="8" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="RDate" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="9" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="PDate" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="10" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="BOption" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="11" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="RSCode" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="12" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="CPAssigment" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="13" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Status" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="14" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

But just in case here is a sample file (fake data)

```
FFILECompany,Account Name,Home Address,Account Number,Service Number,Bill Number,Delivery Service,LPC,RDate,PDate,BOption,RSCode,CPAssignment,Status
Company A,NORM W MYERS,0 X   WEST STREET STRONGHURST IL 61480,6996293052,439998937,5,DS1,DSHDHD-HP,2014-01-02,,BILL,,,ACTIVE
Company B,ROSABEL BLESKIN,982001 RUSTIC ST ROBINSON IL 62466,1499936152,53875283,13,DS1,RDDD-HP,2014-10-10,,BILL,,,ACTIVE
Company C,TIEE E DISNEY,140505 BEL AIRE DR BELLEVILLE IL 62299,1058999074,40564211,10,DS1,RESSS-HP,2015-01-11,2015-11-09,BILL,,,PENDING INACTIVE
Company D,STEVE BROWN,1044920 COLLEGE AVE ALTON IL 62154,1048999118,54999928,2,DS1,RSS-HP,2014-06-26,,BILL,,,ACTIVE
```

And finally, here is my stored procedure:
As you can see I only import a few columns:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AccountImport]
    @Commodity NVARCHAR(255) , -- Hard Coded value inside the map
    @LDCCode NVARCHAR(2) , -- Hard Coded value inside the map
    @AccountNumber NVARCHAR(255) ,
    @AccountName NVARCHAR(255) ,
    @HomeAddress NVARCHAR(255)
AS 
    INSERT  INTO dbo.[CustomerTable]
            ( Commodity ,
              LDCCode ,
              AccountNumber ,
              AccountName ,
              HomeAddress
            )
            SELECT  @Commodity ,
                    @LDCCode ,
                    @AccountNumber ,
                    @AccountName ,
                    @HomeAddress
DECLARE @MID AS INT
SELECT @MID = @@IDENTITY                    


--This stored procedure will parse the address and separate Address city and state using a space
EXEC    [sync].[ParseAddress]   @ID = @MID
```

Again, there are no errors, and one row is imported every time (the first row).

[image]

Comment: What do you have in your MessageAssignment and Transform shapes?  What does the XML sent to the Send Port look like?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set up your schema as an envelope schema to cater for multiple records. See the below links 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa546772.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507336/Envelope-Schema-and-Debatching

Answer (score 0):

How does the message that enter the orchestration look like? If it is only one row, then the problem is in receive pipeline; solution for that:

I think you should define two separate schemas, one for the header of the fileand one for the body of the csv file. Fill inf Flat File Disassembler pipeline like this:

DocumentSchema: BodySchemaName, AssemblyName

HeaderSchema: HeaderName, AssemblyName

If the message in the orchestration is full, without header, only body, then the problem is in the mapping, so you should provide us with more information. What does the schema you map into look like?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the "Max occurs" property on the record node of the inbound schema is set to "unbounded"